# How to show Angular issues in JsFiddle?

Tags: html, angularjs, jsfiddle

I'd like to show an issue with my Angular code so I tried to create a fiddle for it. Since I wasn't sure how to link AngularJS package in (other than entering the **whole** URL, which I'm bound to fail on due to misspelling and laziness), I googled "*how to easy link to angulaarjs in jsfiddle*" and got a fiddle like this: jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/ (among many others).

The poster doesn't actually link to anything (except bootstraping the styles) and I'm not quite clear on why.

I'd like to know if that's the proper way to present an example when asking Angular related questions on StackOverflow. If not, what is?

As a secondary question, I'd like to know how to properly handle the fact that in my example locally, I'm using *ng* directives directly in *html* and *body* (for smaller examples) but JsFiddle explains that those tags, already being included, aren't going to work. Should I move those directives deeper into the markup structure?

Comment: Would Plunker be more useful? Because in Plunker you can auto create basic setting for different versions of AngularJs?

Comment: @Konkko I was under the impression that JsFiddle was **the** resource to turn to when showing examples. Of course, I'm always open to learning new things. Is Plunker as good at adding HTML/CSS/JS as JsFiddle is? (At the current stage, I'm not in need of testing different versions of Angular - "any" will do, as long as it isn't 2.0, hehe).

Comment: Personally I like Plunker when I'm trying out other peoples code problems or just having a look how a script works. You can add libraries but I guess you are meaning that you could just add a file? Like an External Resources in JsFiddle?

Comment: From my view Plunker fits better:
- you have option in menu 'create angular example'
- js/css imports declaration are straightforward and clear - you can just copy files from plunk and this will work 
- angular bootstrap examples (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) have direct links to plunks

Comment: @Konkko Sorry if I was unclear. What I meant was that instead of specifying an URL in my JsFiddle (or Plnkr or whatever else) pointing to the library (be that jQuery, AngularJS or anything), I'd prefer just a combo box so I can pick myself my just klicking. (Of course, if we want a full control over versions etc. that won't do but I imagine that most of the questions aren't dependent to a specific version - the latest one will do.)

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I'll make sure to check it out. I wasn't aware of Plunker before - in fact, I thought that JsFiddle is **the** resource when presenting examples for others to play around with. Are you suggesting that Plunker is a better tool for **all** demonstrations or just when it comes to Angular?

Comment: @KonradViltersten from the right side you can add packages and their dependencies, also look for templates if you like. Adding packages works most of the time, but at least angular-material doesn't seem to work :)